# Is it possible to connect a Route 53 hosted zone to Lightsail Container Service using the apex domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, alias, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

While setting up a new container service in AWS Lightsail I've come across an issue setting up my DNS. As described [here](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-point-domain-to-container-service) I am not able to route the traffic for the apex of my domain (querowebdesign.com) to the container service itself using the Lightsail DNS service, so I was looking at using Route 53 to manage my DNS and leverage alias records to provide this capability. However, when attempting to create a Route 53 alias A record I don't seem to be able to route directly to a Lightsail container service.

So a couple of questions - firstly, does my approach make sense, and secondly is this possible at all?

Comment: I think it make sense. I'm trying to solve the same problem. It seams that in order to link an arbitrary resource to Route 53 you need a static IP on you container instance however Lightsail only able to attach static IP to non-container instances. This is quite frustrating.

Comment: My company assigns to me a project with a hosted domain `project-a.my-company.com`, I have to go with `https://www.project-a.my-company.com` for production, and `https://staging.project-a.my-company.com` for staging. All environments are deployed on LightSail containers

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is possible with this page

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-point-domain-to-container-service

Comment: I did this, and it does not work. I also added a second JSON object to the `Changes` property for a subdomain, and my subdomain works. So the issue seems to be with the apex somehow. I still have not solved this.